# How to show timer in InAppBrowser (Ionic 4 Cordova)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, browser

I am creating a hybrid mobile app in ionic 4 angular 7.

I am using cordova InAppBrowser to open url in system browser. Everthing till now is working.

But i want following more things

1- Want to show a timer in browser for x seconds, if user closed browser in less than x second then it should either not allow or have track.

2- want to capture browser start  event and close event

Answer (score 0):

You can not change or add the behaviour of URL that you are opening in App browser but I think can add a timer in ionic for how many seconds the browser was opened.

**Listen close event**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }

const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.stackoverflow.com');
// Start timer here as in app browser tab created by above line.

browser.on('exit').subscribe(() => {
    // Browser tab closed so you can stop timer
}, err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

The start event is one when `iab` tab created.